# Separating audit and logging from response time - Design

Tags: database, jakarta-ee

I have a simple Web based application scenario,Sending a request and get response from Database.Response would be having very large number of rows say around 10,000 to 20,000 of records at a time.

I have designed for Audit Logging for all transaction.i.e.Inserting into database for all such responses.say 10,000 to 20,000 rows at a time.

As,Inserting into the table is just for auditing purpose.Can I have some way to separate Auditing and Logging from Normal response ? Some way to differentiate them ?

Any help on design would be highly appreciable.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checkout ***log4j2*** for seperating auditing and logging.

> This is easily done by having two appenders in the log4j2.xml itself.

For reference visit:

https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html

Answer (score 1):

In general, it's a bad idea for a web application to do too much work in a synchronous web request. Web servers (and web application servers) are designed to serve lots of concurrent requests, but on the assumption that each request will take just milliseconds to execute. Different servers have different threading strategies, but as soon as you have long-running requests, you're likely to encounter an overhead due to thread management, and you can then very quickly find your web server slowing down to the point of appearing broken.

Reading or writing 10s of thousands of rows in a single web request is almost certainly a bad idea. You probably want to design your application to use asynchronous worker queues. There are several solutions for this; in the Java ecosystem, you could check out [vert.x](http://vertx.io/)

In these asynchronous models, auditing is straightforward - your auditor subscribes to the same message queue as the "write to database" listener.